# Is there a way to disable the js of the Views Display Tabs module without hacking the module?

Tags: views

I'm using [Views Display Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/viewsdisplaytabs) module and it works really well. My problem is that I'm using Views exposed filters as a block. When I switch between tabs the filters don't get updated because they are in a  block and the module uses js to switch between tabs, so the page doesn't get refreshed. I would like to know a way to disable the js functionality of the module without hacking it. Ideally the module would have a setting for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard practice for adding javascript is to use `Drupal.behaviors` to execute your modules code when appropriate.

This gives an easy way to override modules javascript by redefining that modules behavior. For Views Display Tabs I took a look at their [javascript source](http://drupalcode.org/project/viewsdisplaytabs.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/viewsdisplaytabs.js#l119) to see that the behavior was called `Drupal.behaviors.viewsDisplayTabs`.

So now you can [add your own javascript](http://drupal.org/node/304255) to override this:

```
//Override Views Display Tabs javascript
Drupal.behaviors.viewsDisplayTabs = function() {}
```